# Uploading JSON File as Multimedia Component in SDL Tridion 2011

Tags: asp.net, json, iis-7, mime-types, tridion

I am trying to upload JSON files in Tridion and publish them. I have created a new multimedia type for JSON files with MIME Type : application/json

I have then uploaded the file as multimedia component and published the file. I can see the file created at the delivery server, but when I try to read the file from the URL, it shows File Not Found.

I am using ASP.NET application at Delivery Server with IIS 7.5

Do I need to do some other configuration? Please Help.

Thanks & Regards

Sharad Kumar Sangal

Comment: That looks like an IIS configuration issue... see here http://www.uipress.com/add-json-handler-support-in-iis-7/#.UQuK82dfJEI

Comment: Yes, for some reason unknown to man IIS responds to unknown mime types with a 404..

Answer (score 4):

You will need to add your file extension and mime type to IIS. If you need help doing so check out this link:

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap

The actual values you need are probably `.json` for the file name extension and  `application/json` for the MIME type.

Comment: If you find SO helpful for solving your Tridion questions - Please consider committing to the Area 51 proposal at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=eo63snjNlUWNn9xqeeO2NA2 using your SO account - The SDL Tridion community really needs all the support we can get.